# How to call a Servlet (JEE5) with Phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I have to develop a project that is composed by a JEE5 server and a 
mobile client (iPhone) that will consume the jobs.

Can I do it with Phonegap? If yes, how can I call/consume the jobs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an XMLHttpRequest, just as you would in a regular web application.

There are [tons of blog posts and articles out there that explain the basics](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=xhr+web+service).